# UBUNTU 14.04 Gui text and pictures displaying problem like a virus

Tags: intel-graphics, gui

I might have a problem with Ubuntu 14.04 with a brand new laptop Lenovo T450s - it looks like a virus. 
It appeared after the laptop had to be restarted and I hope it is just some corrupted file.

Anti-virus did not find anything.

So it looks like some letters are replaced with random new letters or they're just missing. It appears with different intensity after restart, but does not disappear. 
It affects the GUI and also Firefox, synaptic and other programs, but not all. Skype is fine, terminal is fine. It appears even under the guest session.

Is it a virus? If yes which anti-virus for Ubuntu can find it and if not how to fix it?

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

```
olga@olga:~$ sudo lshw -class display
[sudo] password for olga: 
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:61 memory:e0000000-e0ffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:3000(size=64)
```

Comment: Your picture isn't visible. Try opening up it's sharing settings - or putting it somewhere non-FB users can see it.  Virus is unlikely - font or video driver?

Comment: As @MarkWilliams says. Please help us help you by uploading the image to imgur.com and [edit]ing your question to remove the old and add the new link so that we can see it. thank you!

Comment: Please upload the picture in http://imgur.com put the link in by [editing](http://askubuntu.com/posts/607232/edit) your question.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/WvSoNJM.png - here is the picture. Is it now visible?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide the output of `sudo lshw -class display`

Answer (score 5):

This being caused by a virus is very unlikely.

I have the same problem, also Ubuntu 14.04 on Thinkpad T450s, and the following workaround that someone suggested on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/linux/+bug/1432194) works for me, although it has a noticeable negative impact on graphics performance:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/
sudo -H gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

Add the following to the file, save it and reboot:

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
  Driver      "intel"
  Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
EndSection
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like it is working and hopefully will not come back.