# Graphics and font problem in Ubuntu 14.04 with Intel Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics

Tags: 14.04, graphics, intel-graphics, fonts

My fonts, windows are often affected by graphic distorisions, bugs, sometimes disapear without any reasons.

When I reboot it is generally solved.

This is happening since I update my kernel and graphics, but I don't know how to solve it.

I have a Dell XPS 13 running ubuntu 14.04, with Intel HD5500.

Output of lspci -k | grep VGA -A2

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
Subsystem: Dell Device 0665
Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Output of dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-core

```
rc  xserver-xorg-core                                     2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.7                                 amd64        Xorg X server - core server
ii  xserver-xorg-core-lts-utopic                          2:1.16.0-1ubuntu1.2~trusty2                         amd64        Xorg X server - core server
```

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add there output of "lspci -k | grep VGA -A2" terminal command.

Comment: And also "dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-core"

Comment: It looks like a bug in the newer intel driver.

Comment: So I can't do anything about it ?

Comment: You can revert xorg to the previous version

Comment: All right, so what do you suggest me :) ?

Comment: Is your system 64-bit?

Comment: Yes it is indeed

Comment: Last question. How did you upgrade your kernel and graphics?

Comment: You helped me there lol : http://askubuntu.com/questions/624979/background-freezes-weirdly-in-ubuntu-14-04/624984?noredirect=1#comment886110_624984

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution seems to have **partially** fixed it for me [UBUNTU 14.04 Gui text and pictures displaying problem like a virus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607232/ubuntu-14-04-gui-text-and-pictures-displaying-problem-like-a-virus?rq=1)

But instead of the following :

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
  Driver      "intel"
  Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
EndSection
```

I have set the **AccelMethod** to `sna`

Indeed, `UXA` was giving me terrible lag

Comment: This is not a real solution, but a workaround. But workable.

Comment: Yes that's what I tought, but still it seems to be working pretty well, less buggy, and graphics are also working faster so I will stick with it until Intel releases a knew driver, as you adviced

Comment: For more information on what this actually does, see `man 4 intel` or https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics#Troubleshooting. I have seen similar problems with 15.04 on a new laptop with Broadwell Intel Integrated graphics, but as far as I can tell  `sna` mode is used by default - verified through `grep -i uxa /var/log/Xorg.0.log` from the comments here: http://cynic.cc/blog/posts/sna_acceleration_vs_uxa/

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug in Intel graphics drivers. There is no vivid HWE for trusty yet. So you can do one of these:

1. Wait till new HWE appears in Ubuntu repositories. It is a matter of a week or two, then upgrade to it. I prefer this.
2. Install Ubuntu 15.04.
3. Do 2 + Intel graphics installer. (I do not like this)