# Window freezes when mouse and keyboard button pressed at same time

Tags: keyboard, mouse, freeze

I have a number of "gaming" mice with extra buttons, including a Logitech G602, Corsair Scimitar, Razer Naga, etc. All of these mice seem to exhibit a common bug using Ubuntu, that is when pressing an input button on the mouse and one on the keyboard at the same time, the focused window freezes for a few seconds. In some things like games, that's a huge problem. In web browsers and so on it's annoying, but not a big issue.

Is there a known fix to this issue or is there a driver I should be specifically using that might alleviate it? Note that I'm using unofficial third party drivers for all the mice, but I'm fairly confident it's an issue with the OS, not the input device, since it's common between three devices and countless applications.

Right now I'm using Ubuntu 17.04 with Gnome nut I've seen this on Unity, Kubuntu, elementary, and Xubuntu, on 14.04, 16.04, and 17.04 in various configurations.

Mouse driver for current configuration (Corsair Scimitar) is CKB: https://github.com/ccMSC/ckb

Keyboard right now is KBC Poker 3 using whatever default driver is selected for it. I've got a few other boards around and a Ducky Shine TKL produced the issue, as did a Razer BlackWidow.

Computer specifications: AMD FX8350, Gigabyte 990fxa-ud3 (known to have some USB issues, but the 4 working ports are all behaving the same), EVGA GTX770SC graphics card.

Comment: Try enable TouchPad while typing,  Mouse > Touchpad > and uncheck "disable touchpad while typing" and let me know if it's fixed, or change the USB ports of mouse and keyboard to different ports or test with different mouse  and keyboard (in PC)

Comment: ***"I'm using unofficial third party drivers for all the mice"*** Can you edit your question with the names and versions of these drivers? Also any other relevant information about your platform: computer make, model, CPU, etc.

Comment: Check if `~/.xsesssion-errors` has errors for when you reproduce the problem. Also run strace with some app, e.g. `strace gedit` from a terminal, reproduce the bug, and check if strace output stops for when the window freezes. If it is, then add to the post, say, 8-9 lines of the output with a mark at which line did it hang.

Comment: @αғsнιη No options for disabling touchpad while typing, this is a desktop computer. Tried a few ports, but most are non-functional so I only have 6 to choose from (motherboard has known issues booting some USB ports). Thanks.

Comment: @Hi-Angel No ~/.xsession-erors, I'm on Gnome DE at the minute, so I guess Gnome Shell would be the equivalent? Not sure what to look at. Thanks.

Comment: @XtrmJosh does the issue happen without the custom driver? Also, note that the project you linked to [been deprecated in favor of its fork](https://github.com/mattanger/ckb-next#what-happened-to-the-original-ckb), did you try it?

Comment: @Hi-Angel Sorry, I should've linked to the forked repo, the old one doesn't work at all as it doesn't support my device. Without the custom driver, the buttons in question don't work at all. I don't think I specifically said, it's only the additional mouse buttons which cause the issue, so it's impossible to reproduce without the driver. Left, right, and middle mouse buttons all work and don't cause an issue, nor does scrolling. Any of the 12-key numpad buttons do.

Comment: @XtrmJosh ok, it's definitely a bug. I can't say offhand where exactly, but ATM I think the best would be to report the issue to ckb-next, and let them to figure that out. Also you didn't reply the part of my comment about `strace`. Given the circumstances, I don't really need it, just note that this output would be a nice bit of information to add to your bugreport.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Sorry I missed that part. Running with `strace` froze the output as well as the window. I should note, I'm still not convinced this is an issue with ckb, because I've seen the exact same problem using a Razer Naga, and the Logictech G602 (Logitech not requiring any custom drivers, Naga I don't recall exactly which driver). I have actually returned both of those now so cannot re-test with them, but I'm confident the issue is with a component of the OS, not the drivers.

Comment: @XtrmJosh nice, if `strace` got completely frozen — the better. The devs that gonna study your bugreport just need to know at what system call the freeze happens. And I do not claim that the problem is in ckb-next. Let's think, where would you report? It's unspecific to a DE. You said it happens in apps as well as games — so neither it specific to a toolkit. You're left with XServer and ckb-next. If you report it to XServer, they'd sure say *it's ckb-next's fault* — because why not? So the best is to report to ckb-next, and let them sort that out. Or, you could try debugging it yourself ☺

Answer (score 1):

I would have left a comment, but I haven't enough reputation. I had a similar problem and the problem was the graphic driver.

Every time the freeze happened, the system log file (`/var/log/syslog`) contained lines like this:

```
... kernel: [drm] GPU HANG: ecode 9:0:0x84dffff8, in Xorg [2082], reason: Hang on render ring, action: reset
... kernel: drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
... kernel:  [drm] RC6 off
... kernel:  [drm] GuC firmware load skipped
```

The solution was to disable [`SNA` if favor of `UXA` acceleration](https://askubuntu.com/a/626001/454520).

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in syslog, is it possible that you've enabled some enhanced logging for this reason?

Comment: I think this qualifies as an answer. Plus it's too large to fit into a comment with proper formatting.